# position of hyperlink when ppt with hyperlink to image

Tags: image, powerpoint

I will try to convert ppt to image using program(C# or Java).
I can search this solution in the Stackoverflow but the problem is the following:

The ppt has some hyperlink such as "go to next Page" and "go to specific slide".

How can I know where the hyperlink is at the image when I convert ppt to image?

Any Language is Ok....if I can find out the position of hyperlink at image.

Answer (score 0):

Each slide has a hyperlinks collection that contains all of the hyperlinks on the slide.
Look at each hyperlink's .Type property.

If .Type = msoHyperlinkShape, you can get the hyperlink's coordinates by walking the .Parent chain up to the parent shape; use the shape's coordinates.

If .Type = msoHyperlinkRange, the hyperlink has been applied to text rather than to a shape, so you walk up the .Parent chain to the textrange that represents the hyperlinked text.  The text range will have BoundLeft, BoundTop, BoundHeight, BoundWidth properties that give you the coordinates of the hyperlink.

From there, it's ratios ...

LinkLeft / SlideWidth = x / ImageWidthInPixels

Solve for x to get the distance in pixels from the left of the image to the left of the hyperlink position.